# Ruby performance with multiple lines of code

Tags: ruby, performance

Are there any differences in performance between these two code implementations?

First implement:

```
class AppSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :device, :identify, :token, :color
end
```

Second implement:

```
class AppSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name,
             :device,
             :identify,
             :token,
             :color
end
```

Which is better for performance?

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark your code? What was the result?

Comment: @HolgerJust oh, Thank you for reminding me. I will try it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would there be a performance difference?

Comment: @jvillian I think when run code with many lines, it means more time, right?

Comment: Why do you think that? The same code functions no matter what. Performance is based on implementation not how many lines of code are in your application. The example you provided is just a style difference- some prefer how the top looks, others prefer how the bottom looks.

Comment: There *may* be a miniscule measurable difference in the time it takes to parse the file, but I suspect you'll notice any difference at all. But by all means, benchmark it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntactically these two are identical, there's no difference. When the Ruby parser engages on this code there will be an almost immeasurable increase in time required to process the newline characters, but we're talking about perhaps a handful of clock-cycles on a CPU that's going to be running at 2 *billion* clocks per second or more. That's, at best, *nanoseconds*.

Additionally, this statement is run only once, when the model is created, so a tiny performance impact like that will be difficult to measure. The temperature of your CPU, which impacts CPU speed, is far more significant, and that will fluctuate enough that getting a good read here is impossible.

Fewer lines is not faster. Fewer characters is not faster. Performance is independent of that.

If you're ever curious about performance, benchmark it, but that's only relevant for code that's substantially different. In this case the code is identical apart from formatting.

The reasoning behind the design of Ruby is to make things faster for the developer, that you can *express* your intent quickly, concisely, and in a manner that's easy to read back later. This comes at the cost of performance but as Ruby developers we make that concession willingly.

If something has to be fast, there's always ways of optimizing it, but it's important to avoid premature optimization. If it works, and it performs adequately for your use case, spend your time solving new problems rather than rehashing old ones.